# Cockroach olfactory bulb response to novel stimuli

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, reference-request

[I've heard anecdotally](https://github.com/ctn-waterloo/modelling_ideas/issues/18), that the cockroach olfactory bulb responds differently to novel stimuli vs. known stimuli. Specifically, it sends an oscillatory firing pattern for known stimuli and a constant firing pattern for novel stimuli. However, I'm having a hard time finding a reference for this? Does the olfactory bulb in insects (not just cockroaches) actually respond with different firing patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Kay and Stopfer (2006) in their paper, [Information processing in the olfactory systems of insects and vertebrates](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.semcdb.2006.04.012), it looks as though oscillatory firing patterns in insects fire as a mechanism for categorizing *all smells, novel and familiar:*

> Several imaging techniques that assess afferent or principal neuron 
>   responses all indicate that odor stimulation evokes maps of activity 
>   that vary with the odorant; not all odorants activate all glomeruli and principal neurons.

More specifically:

> In both insects and vertebrates, odor stimulation elicits the oscillatory synchronization of responsive principal neurons.

Note that no distinction is being made here between *novel and familiar* olfactory stimuli. It seems that much of the research on novel olfactory stimuli as related to olfactory bulb firing patterns has been done on vertebrates, as discussed [here.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-9384(94)90205-4)